# install staDA package

Tags: r, install.packages

I tried to install the package statDA without success.These are the last rows of the message I received in RStudio:

```
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (geoR)
ERROR: dependency ‘MBA’ is not available for package ‘StatDA’
* removing ‘/home/matteo/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/StatDA’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘StatDA’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpwirNxx/downloaded_packages’
```

I also tried to install the MBA package but actually the same error appeared. 
I'm on a Ubuntu (12.04) machine running R 3.0.

Comment: Have you tried installing MBA: `install.packages("MBA")` Then trying `geoR` again.

Comment: I was able to install geoR. Then I tried to install both MBA and StatDA but same errors appeared.

Comment: What error do you get when you try `install.packages("MBA")`

Comment: You definitely don't get the same errors, since MBA isn't a dependency for MBA!

Comment: MBA is dependent on boost headers. You may need to install that externally for MBA to install.

Comment: The error for MBA is configure: error: Boost header files not found. Under linux/Unix try R CMD INSTALL MBA_0.0-0.tar.gz --configure-args='--with-boost-include=INCLUDE_PATH'
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘MBA’
* removing ‘/home/matteo/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/MBA’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘MBA’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpwirNxx/downloaded_packages’

Comment: How can I install the boost headers?

Comment: I try to install package BH directly in RStudio but the error remains when I try to install MBA.